# Rules for Reading scriptures

Tags: scripture, puranas, practice

I am very much intrested in reading every hindu mythology scriptures. I know that in my life time it may not be possible. But would like to cover as many as possible. My daily schedule is very busy. So i would like to understand if there is any sin in reading scriptures in office ( in break of free time, wearing shoes ) and reading them before sleeping ( reading while lying on bed etc) or while travelling or any odd time.

Comment: No, it is not a sin in reading scriptures in office and reading them before sleeping, but it is a sin thinking they were a myth. Hindu dharma scriptures are called Vedas meaning "knowledge". How "knowledge" (Veda) may be a myth?

Comment: @brahmajijnasa I don't think Rakesh meant myth as in falsehood, he just meant mythology as in stories that are part of Hinduism. Mythology need not be false; see here: http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/293/36

Comment: Yes, i strongly believe that whatever was mentioned in scriptures has happend and real. I used myth word instead of calling them a story.